# install postgresql on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to install postgresql on ubuntu 19.10 (Eoan). I've tried many ways but it seems that even the newest version of postgresql (12) is not supported.
Does anyone know if it can be installed in some way?

this is the error I get when I'm trying to install, for example, postgresql 11:

```
$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-11
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql-11 : Depends: postgresql-client-11
                 Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libpq5 (>= 9.3~) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but it is not installable
                 Recommends: sysstat but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: I have no problem doing `sudo apt-get install postgresql-11` on a fresh 19.10 install.  Did you install 19.10 fresh, or upgrade from some earlier distribution?  What else have you installed?  What other repositories do you have configured?  Have you done update and upgrade with apt recently?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
https://askubuntu.com/a/1074728

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libicu55
```